# How to generate private key from 24-word mnemonic phrase? (Native Segwit)

Tags: private-key, electrum, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed, seed

When Googling, entire first page consists of people linking to online "calculators" (no thank you) or outdated bip39 code which no longer works. I have a 24 word seed phrase (from ledger live), and I need to turn it into a private key so that I can import it into electrum. How can I do this (locally)?

Comment: Why do you not want to [restore the wallet from the seed phrase](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-standard-wallet-from-seed/) selecting BIP39 in step 4? Thats the usual way to generate all the private keys.